# java static field from null

Tags: java, static, nullpointerexception

I found this code on the Internet, and would love for someone to explain it to me...

```
public class Foo {
    static int fubar = 42;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(((Foo) null).fubar);
    }
}
```

This code compiles and works correctly, outputting the result `42`.

How is it possible that the variable `fubar` is accessed from a `null` without throwing a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I love this question.  It's short, to-the-point, and highlights how a particular language feature might work in ways that seem counterintuitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the field `fubar` is declared `static`, there is only one field anywhere actually named `Foo.fubar`.  Each instance of `Foo` shares this one copy.  When you access this field out of a `Foo` object, Java doesn't try following the object reference to find it.  Instead, it looks up the object in a specially-defined location that can be accessed independently of any reference.  Consequently, if you try looking up this field of the `null` object, you can do so without causing any sort of `NullPointerException`, since the object is never referenced.

**EDIT**: Bytecode is definitely in order!  Given this source file:

```
public class Foo {
    static int fubar;
    public Foo() {
        ((Foo)null).fubar = 137;
    }
}
```

Here's the generated bytecode:

```
0:  aload_0
1:  invokespecial   #1; //Method Object."<init>":()V
4:  aconst_null
5:  checkcast   #2; //class Foo
8:  pop
9:  sipush  137
12: putstatic   #3; //Field fubar:I
15: return
```

Notice that line 12 uses the `putstatic` opcode, which stores a value into a `static` field.  It doesn't reference a receiver object of any sort.  In fact, if you'll notice, the generated bytecode (lines 4-8) does a cast of `null` to `Foo`, but then immediately issues a `pop` opcode to pop it off the stack.  It's never referenced anywhere else in the bytecode.

Comment: True (+1). Bonus points if showing some byte-code for `Foo.fubar` and `((Foo)null).fubar` to show the implicit compiler transformation more clearly....

Comment: @pst- That's a **great** idea.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 10):

It's not actually looking for the field on `null`, because static methods and fields don't require an instance. The cast makes the type of the expression `Foo`, and `fubar` is a known *static* field on `Foo`, so the compiler and JVM have no issue.

Normally, you'd access the field by saying `Foo.fubar`. However, Java is nice enough to provide a shortcut: if you try to access a static field or method on an instance expression of a given type, it will treat it as if you had said `[SomeType].theField`. That's what's occurring here.

Comment: +1 Yes :) The compiler *should* (at least it has in my experience) also issue a nice warning indicating that a static field should be accessed directly off the type and not an instance of said type.

Answer (score 1):

fubar is a static member this cast of null just highlights the allocation of static variables at compile time rather than runtime.  A much more common and equivalent way of accessing the static variable is this `Foo.fubar`